# Loading screen for svg web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, ecmascript-6, snap.svg

My website consists of many pages in `.svg` format, wich are rather big files, is there any way to display some simple loading animation while my `.svg` pages load?

**Note :**

Please be aware that my question is for `.svg` page format file, not `<html>` pages. I already know how to put loading animation into `<div id="loader">` and fade it out using JQuery, thank you....

Answer (score 0):

what you mean  "svg page fromat" ? svg can embed in html, like other embed resources, so you can show loader when starts svg  loading and hide it after loading complete.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload='load(evt)'>
```

and close loading in load function.

Comment: I have tried to `<embed>` my `.svg` file and have also tried to put it inline to a `<html>` file, both approach caused another problem arise as i describe in my other topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136886/problems-with-my-inline-svg-and-embeded-svg